# How to get save an image at location and retrieve it for imageView in Android App?

Tags: java, android, image, file

I am building a **simple camera app in Android** to show it in a `imageView` .I can get thumbnail which is very blurr .So I have a made file for that and then It  gives me the location of the file. When I check it ,Its is of 0 kb which is well understood .
My Task is to  capture image  and save  at `mCurrentPhotoPath` and I should be able to display it in my `imageView` in `startActivityForResult()`

But **App Crashes** Before Caling Before that again and again.
I know something is buggy in this line

```
 Uri photoURI = FileProvider.getUriForFile(MainActivity.this,"com.infolabs.photu", photoFile);
```

.I have changed  `Uri photoURI = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this,            "com.example.android.fileprovider",photoFile);` to `com.infolabs.photu` .But I can't get whats wrong in it .

**Please have a look at   my code and I have location URL location but It won't show or work as the image is 0KB**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.captureimage);
    imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);


    b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);


            if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null)
            {
                // Create the File where the photo should go
                File photoFile = null;
                try
                {
                    photoFile = createImageFile();
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,mCurrentPhotoPath,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                catch (IOException ex)
                {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"the file is not created ",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

                if (photoFile != null)
                {
                    //this Uri does not working properly
                    Uri photoURI = FileProvider.getUriForFile(MainActivity.this,"com.infolabs.photu", photoFile);
                    takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, photoURI);
                    startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_TAKE_PHOTO);
                }
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Error Log:-
 FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                Process: infolabs.photu, PID: 21415
                                                                java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.res.XmlResourceParser android.content.pm.ProviderInfo.loadXmlMetaData(android.content.pm.PackageManager, java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
                                                                    at android.support.v4.content.FileProvider.parsePathStrategy(FileProvider.java:583)
                                                                    at android.support.v4.content.FileProvider.getPathStrategy(FileProvider.java:557)
                                                                    at android.support.v4.content.FileProvider.getUriForFile(FileProvider.java:399)
                                                                    at infolabs.photu.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:71)
                                                                    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5269)
                                                                    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21556)
                                                                    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:815)
                                                                    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:104)
                                                                    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:207)
                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5776)
                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789)
                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:679)
04-17 16:56:15.085 21415-21425/infolabs.photu I/System: FinalizerDaemon: finalize objects = 65

Comment: if it crashes then post your crash logs too.

Comment: Could you please add a debug point at " Uri photoURI = FileProvider.getUriForFile(MainActivity.this,"com.infolabs.photu", photoFile); " and open the file manually and check the size of the file.

Comment: Yes I did it shows 0kb

Comment: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B75k1pht3vgSMnhMR2NnbkFOZjg

Comment: You should use `Uri.fromFile(photoFile)`

Comment: Thank You so much Sir , Omar Aflak  for that hint . It strscuked there from last 3 hours .It saved the image in the folder .

Answer (score 2):

Capture the image from Camera and save it to sdcard:

```
cameraBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
 {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View v) 
{

         Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

                    try {

                        File f = createImageFile();//createImageFile() is added.
                        if (f != null) {
                            intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(f));
                           startActivityForResult(intent, CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE);
                        }
                    } catch (IOException IOE) {
                        IOE.printStackTrace();
                    }

                            }
                        });


         private File createImageFile() throws IOException {

                String imageFileName = "image";
                String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
                imageFileName = imageFileName + timeStamp.toString();
                File albumF = getStorageDir();
                File imageF = File.createTempFile(imageFileName, ".jpg", albumF);
                return imageF;

            }

         private File getStorageDir() {
                File storageDir = null;
                storageDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "/MyApp" );
                if (storageDir != null) {
                    if (!storageDir.mkdirs()) {
                        if (!storageDir.exists()) {
                            Log.d("CameraSample", "failed to create directory");
                            return null;
                        }
                    }
                }
                return storageDir;
            }



        private File getImageFile() {
            String Path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/MyApp";
            File f = new File(Path);
            File imageFiles[] = f.listFiles();

            if (imageFiles == null || imageFiles.length == 0) {
                return null;
            }

            File lastModifiedFile = imageFiles[0];
            for (int i = 1; i < imageFiles.length; i++) {
                if (lastModifiedFile.lastModified() < imageFiles[i].lastModified()) {
                    lastModifiedFile = imageFiles[i];
                }
            }
            return lastModifiedFile;
        }
```

// overwrite the method from activity, read the save image file and show in the ImageView:

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
  if (requestCode == CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE) {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

                File imageFile = getImageFile();

Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imageFile.getAbsolutePath());
                    mImageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

}}}
```

Add permission in the menifest file:

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can try the Picasso library, it is very easy and will solve most of your problems relating to handling images.
You can find it here: http://square.github.io/picasso/

Comment: Sir , My Problem is to first capture the image and save it properly .then I can picaso to load from sdcard.

Comment: Then @VivekGautam, if you could post the crash logs, then it would be helpful to find out the problem.